# How to Update schema of Mogodb Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am facing issue to add new field in mongodb existing collection schema.
I have already a collection in my mongodb database by using the below angular model code.

```
var MessageTypeSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  from: {},
  content: {type: String, required: true},
  parent_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
  parent_message: {},
  **likes: {type: String,required: false}**,
  created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

I want to add that bold likes field in my collection i did this in my existing code which is running fine.
but new likes field is not added when i chat.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

use the MongoDB Compass https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass tool to connect to your bass to give
use MongoSh
[MongoSh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZrBX.png)

**write this request by modifying collection by the no of your collection**

```
db.getCollection('collection').updateMany({}, {$set: {"likes": '' }})
```

this query will add the field like to your entire collection

Comment: Thanx @Jocelyn for reply. Actually my code was correct i need to restart my express using nodemon to take my changes. You are right provided solution is for mongodb using compass but i was looking for using Angular, schema model